# Can manhua be in black and white only?

Tags: manga-production

I draw manhua about Chinese emperors and the twelve animals of the Chinese zodiac, etc. I use only black and white colors. Can manhua be drawn in black and white only?

Comment: From the tag description: 'If you have technical questions on how to produce Japanese-style comics yourself, consider asking on Graphic Design or Writing instead (per this discussion: https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/are-questions-about-how-to-make-anime-and-manga-off-topic).' While your question is about manhua, I think this would apply as well (I could be wrong, though).

Comment: I think this one would go on Graphic Design, as it's about the artistic aspect of manhua rather than the actual writing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about Graphic Design, which the previous two comments have stated

Comment: While the question was written from a mangaka's POV, I think this question can still be answered by providing some examples of B&W manhua, or nothing.